# What are the units of x,y coordinates in matlab inverse map projection?

Tags: mapping, matlab, map-projections

I have a set of x,y coordinates denoting the outlines of the continents in a Miller Projection in MATLAB.  I'm trying to figure out the MATLAB mapping toolbox and specifically [projinv](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/projinv.html).  The function takes a set of (x,y) coordinates and a projection, and then transforms them into a set of longitude and latitudes.

What I'm confused on is what the units on the (x,y) coordinates should be.  The example in the docs seems to convert them into Survey Feet, but I can't find any documentation on how to properly scale the input mapping.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're asking here...

The Boston roads example in the docs convert units *from* survey feet *into* meters, and then passes them into `projinv`. Thus, (x,y) should be in meters.

Is this what you mean?